# How to unpack result of sub-query into list-type field to result of original query in peewee?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, orm, peewee

How to make peewee put ids of related table rows into additional list-like field into resulting query?

I want to make duplicates detecting manager for media files. For each file on my PC I have record in database with fields like

```
File name, Size, Path, SHA3-512, Perceptual hash, Tags, Comment, Date added, Date changed, etc...
```

Depending on the situation I want to use different patterns to be used to consider records in table as duplicates.

In the most simple case I want just to see all records having the same hash, so I

```
subq = Record.select(Record.SHA).group_by(Record.SHA).having(peewee.fn.Count() > 1)
subq = subq.alias('jq')
q = Record.select().join(q, on=(Record.SHA == q.c.SHA)).order_by(Record.SHA)
for r in q:
    process_record_in_some_way(r)
```

and everything is fine.
But there are lot of cases when I want to use different sets of table columns as grouping patterns. So in the worst case I use all of them except id and "Date added" column to detect exact duplicating rows in database, when I just readded the same file for few times which leads to the monster like

```
subq = Record.select(Record.SHA, Record.Name, Record.Date, Record.Size, Record.Tags).group_by(Record.SHA, Record.Name, Record.Date, Record.Size, Record.Tags).having(peewee.fn.Count() > 1)
subq = subq.alias('jq')
q = Record.select().join(q, on=(Record.SHA == q.c.SHA and Record.Name == q.c.Name and Record.Date == q.c.Date and Record.Size == q.c.Size and Record.Tags == q.c.Tags)).order_by(Record.SHA)
for r in q:
    process_record_in_some_way(r)
```

and this is not the full list of my fields, just example.
Same thing I have to do for other patterns of sets of fields, i.e. duplicating it's list 3 times in select clause, grouping clause of subquery and then listing them all again in joining clause.

I wish I could just group the records with appropriate pattern and peewee would just list ids of all the members of each group into new list field like

```
q=Record.select(Record, SOME_MAJIC.alias('duplicates')).group_by(Record.SHA, Record.Name, Record.Date, Record.Size, Record.Tags).having(peewee.fn.Count() > 1).SOME_ANOTHER_MAJIC
for r in q:
    process_group_of_records(r) # r.duplicates == [23, 44, 45, 56, 100], for example
```

How can I do this? Listing the same parameters trice I really feel like I do something wrong.

Comment: Note the use of the Python "and" does not work. So your "monster" example does not actually work as you think it does. You need to use parentheses around each expression and join them together with "&" -- the binary and. See the note here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT (or for postgres, array_agg) to group and concatenate a list of ids/filenames, whatever.

So for files with the same hash:

```
query = (Record
         .select(Record.sha, fn.GROUP_CONCAT(Record.id).alias('id_list'))
         .group_by(Record.sha)
         .having(fn.COUNT(Record.id) > 1))
```

This is a relational database. So you're dealing all the time, everywhere, with tables consisting of rows and columns. There's no "nesting". GROUP_CONCAT is about as close as you can get.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exact what I need! But GROUP_CONCAT returns string. It's ok for integer, but not for the general case. Is there a way to make it return list instead? Or should I create separate question about it?

Comment: You need to unpack it yourself. You can specify a conversion function in your fn.group_concat() invocation.